# Reordering Bootstrap 3 columns across rows

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a layout that looks something like this:

http://www.bootply.com/hKqgubV4t2

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-2"><div class="well">1</div></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-2"><div class="well">2</div></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-2"><div class="well">3</div></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-2"><div class="well">4</div></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-2"><div class="well">5</div></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-2"><div class="well">6</div></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-2"><div class="well">7</div></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-2"><div class="well">8</div></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-2"><div class="well">9</div></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-2"><div class="well">10</div></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-2"><div class="well">11</div></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-2"><div class="well">12</div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'd like it to look like this for large screens:

```
[ 1][ 2][ 3][ 4][ 5][ 6]
[ 7][ 8][ 9][10][11][12]
```

and this for xs-md:

```
[ 1][ 2][ 3][ 4]
[ 7][ 8][ 9][10]
[ 5][ 6][11][12]
```

The problem is, when I try to add pushes and pulls, I'm getting something like this:

http://www.bootply.com/ysafNpFpsL

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-2"><div class="well">1</div></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-2"><div class="well">2</div></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-2"><div class="well">3</div></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-2"><div class="well">4</div></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-2 col-xs-push-12 col-lg-push-0"><div class="well">5</div></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-2 col-xs-push-12 col-lg-push-0"><div class="well">6</div></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-2 col-xs-pull-6 col-lg-pull-0"><div class="well">7</div></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-2 col-xs-pull-6 col-lg-pull-0"><div class="well">8</div></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-2 col-xs-pull-6 col-lg-pull-0"><div class="well">9</div></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-2 col-xs-pull-6 col-lg-pull-0"><div class="well">10</div></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-2"><div class="well">11</div></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-2"><div class="well">12</div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Result:

```
        [ 1][ 2][ 3][ 4]
        [ 7][ 8]        [ 5][ 6]
[ 9][10]        [11][12]
```

So the pushes and pulls don't cause the divs to wrap around to the next line, and just push them over more.  Is there any way to reorder the columns across these rows?

Comment: You can't put 5 after 10 and so forth with anything built in to Bootstrap. You can use, likely, http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ flexbox -- support on older browser is not supported. http://caniuse.com/flexbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group the rows in two columns (width 8 and width 4), like so:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-3"><div class="well">1</div></div>
      <div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-3"><div class="well">2</div></div>
      <div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-3"><div class="well">3</div></div>
      <div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-3"><div class="well">4</div></div>
      <div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-3"><div class="well">7</div></div>
      <div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-3"><div class="well">8</div></div>
      <div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-3"><div class="well">9</div></div>
      <div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-3"><div class="well">10</div></div>  
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-6 col-lg-6"><div class="well">5</div></div>
      <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-6 col-lg-6"><div class="well">6</div></div>
      <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-6 col-lg-6"><div class="well">11</div></div>
      <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-6 col-lg-6"><div class="well">12</div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Got this working with a small modification: changing the outer row to two rows within the 8 and 4 columns to get rid of the extra gutter between them.